# Getting every HTML object with a specific STYLE property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a javascript function that returns every element in the document that has a specific style property (eg: `background-color`). Ideally, I'd like to pass the value as a parameter so that it only fetches the ones whose property matches that specific value, but unless there's a magical way to do this, getting every object that HAS that property is enough, as I could check everyone to check if the value matches the one I want.

---

Example:

```
<p id="id1" style="color:#DDD"> 
   Hey this is a <b id="id2" style="color:#FFF"> test</b> 
   So <span id="id3" style="background-color:#123"> have a nice 
        <span id="id4" style="color:#DDD">day </span>
      </span>
</p>
```

In this case, assume I wanted:

```
getElementByCSS('color','#DDD')
```

it should return elements **id1** and **id4**

---

I'm using jQuery, I'm betting there must be something in the jQuery library that makes this task simple, but I'm open to other libraries or native JS code if needed. I've been racking my brain but I can't find a simple way of doing this, the answer's probably in some jQuery call.

Thanks in advance!

Bruno

EDIT: Fixed mistake in example, thanks to Alex R. and mplungjan

Comment: I don't think there's a selector filter for that, but would be interesting

Comment: @Bruno, Did you mean `getElementByCSS('color','#DDD')`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? This seems like a bad idea.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: @mplungjan: That will not yield correct results because it will onyl check for inline styles on elements and not cascaded ones set by CSS.

Comment: @Robert: The example had only inline styles

Comment: @Bruno: your example would not find background-color DDD since you only assigned color and not background-color.

Comment: @mplungjan: That's true. Maybe Bruno is not so versed in jQuery and he didn't know about this attribute contains selector filter. So you are right.

Comment: @Alex R. @mplungjan Yes, that's what I meant, color, not background-color. My apologies.

Comment: @Squeegy The reason I have to do this is I'm parsing a poorly made HTML automatically, and I cannot rely on ids or classes to identify the key pieces of information I need to extract. On the other hand I can find those elements by checking their style. I've worked before with python and BeautifulSoup to do similar stuff, but this time I need it on JS client side code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### jQuery selector filter

jQuery selector filters are used to filter HTML elements based on some criteria. In your case its CSS styles hence a selector filter would be most appropriate thing to do. Following code may be a good starting point.

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {
    css: function(element, index, meta, stack) {
        // this should be changed to a regular expresion because colours
        // are reported as rgb(r, g, b) which obviously contains commas as well
        var params = meta[3].split(",");
        var val = $(element).css($.trim(params[0])).toLowerCase();
        return val == $.trim(params[1]).toLowerCase();
    }
});
```

And should be used as:

```
$(":css(font-size, 20px)");
```

[This is a working example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ojore3/5). And to check [its code](http://jsbin.com/ojore3/5/edit).

> **Important**: Upper code in not tested but should be easy to develop further (like checking for parameters, converting values etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the solution:

```
function getElementByCSS(cssPropertyName, valueToMatch, parentToSearch){
  if(parentToSearch == null) parentToSearch = document;
  $(parentToSearch).find('*').filter(function(){
     return $(this).css(cssPropertyName) == valueToMatch;
  });
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$redElements = getElementByCSS("background-color", "red");
```

Third parameter is to limit inside which parent element to search (default `document`, but searching in all the document can be really slow, use this param wisely)

Hope this helps. Cheers